# as am not getting what is the functionality of below code

Tags: reactjs

Can someone explain me below function line by line

```
handleChange(e) {
          let fields = this.state.fields;
          fields[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
          this.setState({
            fields
          });
```

as my understanding

1. we are creating a variable fields and storing the present state of fields in the variable because we cant mute the state.
2. i don't have idea about  `fields[e.target.name] = e.target.value;`
3. updating the fields

can someone explain me the above function line by line?

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow. This forum is to help you to understand why a portion of code is not working but not to explain a language. For that, please, use the manuals for the mentioned technology. See here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fields[e.target.name]** this syntax is also used to access the Object Properties.

```
var obj = {name:'abc', color:'red'}
console.log(obj.name) // this print 'abc'
console.log(obj['name']) // also print 'abc'
```

with obj['xxx'] syntax you can dynamically read and set properties to the object.
reference https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

So in your problem **fields** variable take existing fields object from the local state. And in each event it create new property with that event target name and add that event target value as that new property value. if that property name already exist within the **fields** object then it only modified the value of that property.

So as in your list,

1. is correct. With *let fields = this.state.fields;* it get previously stored values into the **fields** variable. without losing previous data
2. this is what I explained above
3. your answer is correct. update the state with old and new values

Answer (score 0):

This code let's you dynamically change the value of a field in your component state by using object notation. `object[]`

By using `fields[event.target.name]` you're going to look for a field in your component state that matches the name of the element that's causing the event to occur. Then it looks like you're updating the value for that field with `event.target.value`

**Why this is useful**

Let's say you have a component where you want to retrieve multiple inputs from a user. Without object notation, you might end up writing very repetitive code like writing a different event handler for each input in order to determine what field to update in your component state:

**BAD:**

```
handleOnChange1 = (event) => (this.setState({userName: event.target.value}))
handleOnChange2 = (event) => (this.setState({lastName: event.target.value}))
```

However, by naming your elements and coordinating them with a matching field in your component state, you won't have to worry about writing additional event handlers as long as you use object notaton.

**GOOD:**

```
class UserForm extends React.Component{
   state = {
       firstName: "",
       lastName: ""
   }
   handleOnChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      })
   }
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
             <input name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
             <input name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
         </div>
      )
   }

}
```